# Get "Kubernetes error: Unauthorized" when try to configure GitLab CI Runner with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I try to run GitLab CI for private GitLab instance with Kubernetes at GCP following this [instruction](https://gitlab.itechart-group.com/help/user/project/clusters/index#adding-an-existing-kubernetes-cluster).

I got IP of Kubernetes master with `kubectl cluster-info`

Then I created ServiceAccount with kubectl, and also get token with command `kubectl describe secret/SERVICEACCOUNT-XXXXX`

Then I got the certificate with

`kubectl -o json get secret SERVICEACCOUNT-XXXXX | jq -r '.data."ca.crt"' | base64 -d - | tee ca.crt`

I inserted IP, token and ca.crt content in the Kubernetes integration fields for  "Add an existing Kubernetes cluster" command at GitLab.

After that, I tried to install Helm at GitLab, but get an error

```
Something went wrong while installing Helm Tiller
Kubernetes error: Unauthorized
```

Can you help me, please, to find out how to solve these problems?

Comment: You can try adding `--v=10` to `kubectl` commands to get more debug output. This error message is common and points to an authentication/authorization problem, but you would need to know about what actions you are not allowed to perform. In particular Tiller needs wide permissions to modify almost all resources on the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% for gitlab CI but if its building inside the cluster then maybe this https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

RBAC is enabled by default on GKE so you may need to set cluster role permissions for Gitlab so it can spin up containers.